# Returning Nested Object of JSON Data to Mustache Template Using jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mustache

I have links for individual people below in my HTML and on click it should make an Ajax request that populates a mustache template with the correct info for the specific person. What I am trying to do in the JQuery script is use the value attribute in my HTML to identify a nested object within the JSON File to be returned to the template. In the script I have turned this into the variable personIdentifier. Is there any way to use this variable to return only the person specific nested JSON to the template? I am not sure how this could be done. Or if there is an overall better way to do this than my approach. I hope I am explaining this correctly, please feel free to ask me any questions. I feel I am so close, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="clicky" value="jamie">
<a href="">Jamie Info</a>
</div>

<div class="clicky" value="dave">
<a href="">Dave Info</a>
</div>

<script id="people-template" type="text/template">
<div>{{name}}</div>
<div>{{achievements}}</div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.clicky').click( function (event) {
     event.preventDefault(); //to stop from following clicked link
     var personIdentifier = $(this).attr('value');

     $.getJSON( "people.json", function( data ) {
        var template = $('#people-template').html();

        // something here to change the JSON so it 
        // only returns specific persons array/object

        var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $( ".result" ).html( info );


     });
</script>
```

Here is the people.json file (structure can be changed if necessary):

```
    { "people" : {
        "jamie" : [
            {
                "name" : "Jamie Smith",
                "achievements" : "lots of stuff"
            }
        ],
        "dave" : [
            {
                "name" : "Dave Berns",
                "achievements" : "lots of things"
            }
        ]    
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Handlebars, it would be much easier then to implement with your Mustache template as you can use helpers to check the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method could be to change your JSON so that each person has a boolean `(true or false)` value, then using Mustache's templating system you could check all the people and render only those who have the specific value `true` - which you would set once you have received your response from the server.

*UPDATE : You will also need to turn "people" into an array so that it can iterate over each of the individual people... (the JSON below shows this)*

So for example your JSON would look like this...

```
{ 
 "people" : [
    "jamie" : [
        {
            "showPerson" : false
            "name" : "Jamie Smith",
            "achievements" : "lots of stuff"
        }
    ],
    "dave" : [
        {
            "showPerson" : false
            "name" : "Dave Berns",
            "achievements" : "lots of things"
        }
    ]    
  ]
}
```

Now once you get your response from the server you would edit the JSON so that the matching person has the property `showPerson` set to true...

```
"dave" : [
        {
            "showPerson" : true //You can use jQuery to easily do this...
            "name" : "Dave Berns",
            "achievements" : "lots of things"
        }
    ]
```

Now in your Mustache template you would simply have to use the built in `false values` [check](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#false-values-or-empty-lists), if it is `false` then it won't render...

```
<script id="people-template" type="text/template">
    {{#people...showPerson}} //If "showPerson" is `false` this will not render, meaning only the individual you filtered for will display...
        <div>{{name}}</div>
        <div>{{achievements}}</div>
    {{/showPerson}}
</script>
```